# Prove that set is open

Tags: functional-analysis

I have $$ E=C([0,1]; \mathbb{R}), \quad G = \{x \in E: x(0)<0, x(1)>0\}$$
I proved that $G$ isn't closed: $x_0(t) = t \notin G$, but $x(t)=x_0(t)-\min\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\} \in G$,  $x \in B(x_0,  \varepsilon)$. So, $G$ isn't closed (I hope my proof is OK). But how can I prove that $G$ is open?

Comment: Is the topology generated by the $\sup$ norm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, if $x\in G$, then any function $y$ near enough to $x$ should satisfy $y(0) < 0$ and $y(1)>0$.

Formally, let $x\in G$, let $\varepsilon = \min(|x(0)|, |x(1)|)$

Let $y\in E$ such that $\lVert y-x\rVert < \varepsilon$. Then $|y(0)-x(0)|\leq \lVert y-x\rVert$ and $|y(1)-x(1)|\leq \lVert y - x \rVert$, so $y(0)<0$ and $y(1)>0$ (I'll let you show the last step yourself)

Answer (score 0):

The maps $x\mapsto x(0)$ and $x\mapsto x(1)$ are continuous. So $G$ is open as it is the intersection of two preimages of open sets under continuous maps.